# How do you select specific HTML elements with no class or ID using WWW::Mechanize::Firefox?

Tags: perl, web-scraping, www-mechanize, www-mechanize-firefox

I'm trying to loop through links on a page but i only want to loop through specific ones. The problem is that the links in `<a>` anchors do not have CSS ids or classes at all.

eg.

```
<a title="View More Information on FOO" href="tranlist.phtml?scode=FOO&sname=&refpg=1&snapcode=&ssector=1123&scheme=default" name="tranlist">
```

The only thing unique is the `name` but it doesn't seem like it can be specified with CSS selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [*CSS specification*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html), a CSS selector like `a.normal` is the same as `a[class~=normal]`, and you can match any attribute that way. So you need

```
$mech->selector('a[name=tranlist]')
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [module documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3A%3AMechanize%3A%3AFirefox):

`$mech->find_link(name => "something")`

`name_contains` and `name_regex` are also available.

[Edit: `find_link_dom` returns Firefox-specific `MozRepl::RemoteObject::Instance` objects, rather than standard `WWW::Mechanize::Link` objects which are returned by `find_link`. Amended for the more generic case.]